# PyQt widget border color transparent - but button inside normal border

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, border, qpushbutton

I want the border of my QTWidgets.QWidget to be transparent or disabled (borderwidth=0), but when I set it via the stylesheet to "border:0", also all the push buttons inside the widget dont have a border - any idea how to keep the style of the pushbuttons and only change the widget border ?

```
class lamp_frame(object):
    def setupUi(self, window):
        window.setObjectName("Yeelight Controlle")
        window.resize(460, 140+self.window_hight)
        window.setFixedSize(460, 140+self.window_hight)
        self.frame_0 = QtWidgets.QFrame(window)
        self.frame_0.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 30+self.top, 420, 70)) 
        self.frame_0.setStyleSheet("border:0")
        self.frame_0.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_0.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_0.setObjectName("frame_0")

        self.pushButton_0 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_0)
        self.pushButton_0.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 35, 50, 32))
        self.pushButton_0.setObjectName("status")
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Stylesheets are, by definition, *cascading*. From the [wikipedia description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS):

> The style sheet with the highest priority controls the content display. Declarations not set in the highest priority source are passed on to a source of lower priority

This means that if a "generic" property is set on an object without specifying the "target" in any way, every child object will *inherit* that property. Since the buttons are children of the frame, their border will be inherited by it.

It's common convention to specify a *selector* for the target of the properties, in order to correctly apply those properties only to the selected objects.

This means that using a simple "border: 0;" will result in using that border not only on the frame, but also to *all* its children, and that's why these kind of "generic stylesheets" should be avoided, even if they work.

Qt selectors are listed in the [syntax documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types), and in your case you have two options:

- set the stylesheet for the object *class*: `QFrame { border: 0; }`
- use the *object name*: `#frame_0 { border: 0; }`

Obviously, selectors can be mixed according to the needs. To be more specific, since theoretically more object could have the same object name (but Designer won't allow it as it's not a good habit), you could use the following: `QFrame#frame_0 { border: 0; }`