# Window background image changes the style of widgets inside

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

When I use

```
MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background: url(BG.jpg);")
```

the background image is set, but it also makes the other widgets (such as buttons or lines) have that background and look really bad (see picture):
[image: (see picture)].

I tried to set some options for the widgets, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Stylesheets that are intended for a single widget and *not* its child must be set using a specific selector, which you didnt, meaning that all widgets that are children of MainWindow will use that property (remember: stylesheets are *cascading*). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65163546/pyqt-widget-border-color-transparent-but-button-inside-normal-border/65163651#65163651